# For each unique item in a redshift sql column, get the last rows based on a looking/scanning window

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

| patient_id | alert_id | alert_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | xyz | 2022-10-10 |
| 1 | anp | 2022-10-12 |
| 1 | gfe | 2022-10-10 |
| 2 | fgy | 2022-10-02 |
| 2 | gpl | 2022-10-03 |
| 1 | gdf | 2022-10-13 |
| 2 | mkd | 2022-10-23 |
| 1 | liu | 2022-10-01 |

I have a sql table (see simplified version above) where for each `patient_id`, I want to only keep the latest alert (i.e. last one) that was sent out in a given window period e.g. `window_size = 7`.

Note, the window size needs to look at consecutive days i.e. between `day 1` -> `day 1 + window_size`. The ranges of `alert_timestamp` for each `patient_id` varies and is usually well beyond the `window_size` range.

Note, that the table example given above, is a very simple example and will have many more `patient_id`'s and will be in a mixed order in terms `alert_timestamp` and `alert_id`.

The approach is to start from the last `alert_timstamp` for a given `patient_id` and work back using the `window_size` to select the alert that was the last one in that window time frame.

Please note the idea is to have a scanning/looking window, example `window_size = 7 days` to move across the timestamps of each patient

The end result I want, is a table with the filtered out alerts

Expected output for (this example) `window_size = 7`:

| patient_id | alert_id | alert_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | liu | 2022-10-01 |
| 1 | gdf | 2022-10-13 |
| 2 | gpl | 2022-10-03 |
| 2 | mkd | 2022-10-23 |
| 3 | xyz | 2022-10-10 |

What's the most efficient way to solve for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the last_value window function but you need to prep your data a bit.  Here's an example of what this could look like:

```
create table test (
  patient_id    int,
  alert_id  varchar(8),
  alert_timestamp date); 
  
insert into test values
(3, 'xyz', '2022-10-10'),
(1, 'anp', '2022-10-12'),
(1, 'gfe', '2022-10-10'),
(2, 'fgy', '2022-10-02'),
(2, 'gpl', '2022-10-03'),
(1, 'gdf', '2022-10-13'),
(2, 'mkd', '2022-10-23'),
(1, 'liu', '2022-10-01');

WITH RECURSIVE dates (dt) AS
(
  SELECT '2022-09-30'::DATE AS dt UNION ALL SELECT dt + 1
  FROM dates d
  WHERE dt < '2022-10-31'::DATE
),
p_dates AS
(
  SELECT pid,
         dt
  FROM dates d
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT patient_id AS pid FROM test) p
),
combined AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM p_dates d
    LEFT JOIN test t
           ON d.dt = t.alert_timestamp
          AND d.pid = t.patient_id
),
latest AS
(
  SELECT patient_id,
         pid,
         alert_id,
         dt,
         alert_timestamp,
         LAST_VALUE(alert_id IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 7 following) AS at
  FROM combined
)
SELECT patient_id,
       alert_id,
       alert_timestamp
FROM latest
WHERE patient_id IS NOT NULL
AND   alert_id = at
ORDER BY patient_id,
         alert_timestamp;
```

This produces the results you are looking for with the test data but there are a few assumptions.  The big one is that here is at most 1 alert per patient per day.  If this isn't true then some more data massaging will be needed.  Either way this should give you an outline on how to do this.

First need is to ensure that there is 1 row per patient per day so that the window function can operate on rows as these will be equivalent to days (for each patient).  The date range is generated by a recursive CTE and joined to the test data to achieve the 1 row per day per patient.

The "ignore nulls" option is used in the last_value window function to ignore any of these "extra" rows create by the above process.  The last step is to prune out all the unneeded rows and ensure that only the latest alert of the window is produced.

Comment: Thanks for your response- I am a bit confused on the first part that starts with SELECT '2022-09-30'::DATE AS dt UNION ALL SELECT dt + 1 - can you please explain this stage and what it's doing?

Comment: This is the recursive CTE (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html) that produces the dates from '2022-09-30' to '2022-10-31'.   This could be changed to produce the dates from the earliest date for alert_timestamp until the latest date or just use fixed date range as it is now.  This is just an on-the-fly way to make a dates table to ensure all the dates in a range have a row.